# Designer shows error Could not load file or assembly CefSharp.Core

Tags: wpf, cefsharp

The designer complains that

```
Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core, Version=83.4.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

however it is working fine with a normal execution. Only the designer fails to create an overview of my window.

Answer (score 0):

This happened because I was doing some CefSharp initialization inside my window's constructor.

Wrong

```cs
        public Browser()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitCefSharp(); // The designer chokes on this, because the overview of the browser is done in a special exotic environment.
        }
```

Right

```cs
        public Browser()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)) {
              InitCefSharp();
            }
        }
```

I hope it helps some with the same problem.